# Pairing two objects based on common attributes

Tags: c++, c++11

Lets say you have two classes (although in my case one is a struct defined in libc) which share some attributes, but are otherwise different, one of the classes I am able to modify, the other one I am not. In one of the functions I am using I have to pass in a pointer to an array of these structs, yet I would like to see the effects of the call directly in the pairing of the two objects. I have had several ideas as to how to solve this, but they all end up being very unruly and quite unmaintainable. For instance, store the structs in a vector and add a pointer as an attribute to the class I can modify, but that doesn't work as the pointers are generally invalid after erasure (the pointers to the structs after are invalid, but not the ones before the deleted element). Another idea was to use a map between the two, but that doesn't work for a similar reason as I can't use references in the key due to invalidation. Using a duplicate object as a key is also out of the question as that makes deletion quite difficult as well since I need to be able to delete the pairing based on the key or the value.

In my case the objects only have one common attribute, which is unique at a given time, but may not be unique in the lifetime of the process.

I am also restricted to using C++11 as that is the newest version the only compiler I have access to supports.

I'm not really sure how to provide a more helpful code example as it seems sort of trivial, but here is my best attempt:

```cpp
// Class definitions
class A {
    int i;
    ...
};

class B {
    int i;
    ...
};

void F(A*, int num, ...);

int main() {
    ...
    std::vector<A> as;
    std::vector<B> bs;

    F(as.data(), as.size(), ...);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags, like the C language tag for a C++ question.

Comment: As for your problem, perhaps what you're looking for is *templates*?

Comment: Unclear what you want. Do you want generic `F` which modify member `i` (so template might be the solution)? Or do you want to reflect change done in `A` in "corresponding" `B` (based on index or member)?

Comment: @Jarod42 `F` is a function which I have no control over as it is defined in libc. It modifies a some of the parameters in `A`, which I would like to have reflected in `B` so that I dont have to calculate which `A` maps to `B` every iteration.

Comment: what is `F` really?

Comment: `poll` from `poll.h`

Comment: Can you change `A`/`B`, are `as`/`bs` correlated? can those vector be modified?

Comment: I can change `B` but not `A`. About the correlation, that I what I am asking about. Having two vectors of `A`s and `B`s is so far the best way I have to do this, but the connection between the two is quite weak at a glance, so ideally there would be a better way of doing it.